# Pi 4 Doesn't Boot - No apparent issues

Tags: pi-4

Im not sure how or why this happened.  Yesterday this pi worked fine.  Today, it doesn't.  I hadn't done or changed anything so I have to assume it's bricked.
With an SD Card Inserted and power on:
Green LED flickers 1 time and stays off afterwards
Red LED stays on solid
With the SD Card Removed and powered on:
Same
Further Investigation:

Fresh SD Card  ✅

Fresh Raspberry Pi OS  ✅

3.3V  ✅

5V  ✅

Temperature - It does not get hot while sitting powered up, max temp is 30C in an ambient of 22C  ✅[image]

Recovery on Bootloader  ✅

Ref: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151

What else can I do or is it officially bricked somehow?

Comment: What do you see WITHOUT a SD Card?

Comment: @Milliways As it says in the OP, the behavior is identical.  Red light on, green light flickers on _once_ immediately after power on then remains off.

Comment: What (if anything) is displayed on the screen?

Comment: Nothing.  Screen is backlit, no content - as expected because its not booting at all.  No rainbows, no raspberrys, no text, nothing.